# Click only works when clicking div text, not the rest of the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-10

**UPDATE**

I added a jsfiddle with a little more code from the site. This one works like I'm describing. I would of added the extra code sooner but the stylesheet is 1000+ lines and I didn't know what was relevant.

https://jsfiddle.net/noL14v9w/1/

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm in IE10. I have a square div, 300px by 300px. Inside the div, I have some text. If I click the text, it fires my click event. If I click the div but not on the text, it doesn't fire the click event.

The same issue  occurs when I set a CSS hover class. The hover rules only get applied when I hover over the text, not anywhere else in the div.

HTML:

`<div class="openStartAuditButton" onclick="alert('WTF');">asdf</div>`

CSS:

```
.openStartAuditButton{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size:24px;
    background-color:grey;
    color:white;       
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.openStartAuditButton:hover{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

/* I also have box sizing set on all elements, but removing this does nothing: */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   ...
```

Applied Rules:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working for me on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/noL14v9w/), am I missing something?

Comment: what do you mean with "not anywhere else in the div."..

Comment: @scaisEdge I mean anywhere that isn't text. The click only fires if I click the text. If I click the div but not on the text, it doesn't fire. It has a set width and height so the text doesn't fill the div.

Comment: @ScottKaye That fiddle works for me too, I think it could be something else on my site doing it but I have no idea what. I was hoping someone knew a weird quick of IE that caused this and knew the fix.

Comment: Seems to work for me even on IE 9 (IE8 jsFiddle stops working..).

Comment: What's with the downvote? I don't think the issue is in the code I posted. I wasn't even sure if I should of posted the code, because I don't think its there. I think its somewhere else, but I don't know where. I was hoping someone ran into it before.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure those are the only rules being applied to that element??

Comment: @TbWill4321 yes. I added a screenshot of all the rules being applied

Comment: What's the doc type on the document?

Comment: @JECarterII The doctype is in the question

Comment: ah - sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question *why* it happens:

Yes, it is caused by `height:100%`in combination with `z-index:99`.
The 100% height makes the `navHolder` the size of the complete window, and because the `navHolder` has a high z-index (99) it will be on top of all the elements.

Removing the 100% height, will make sure the navHolder does not overlap the elements below anymore, and makes your click work.

Why it did work on the text, is a bit weird (in chrome it does not).

**edit**
I found out why it does weird in IE 10: http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/01/27/ie-bug-text-ignores-z-index-of-higher-elements/.
It is a known bug.

Comment: Thanks, the text having a higher z-index are where my suspicions are too.

Comment: @MrBurger Changed my answer, see the link.

Comment: Yep, I also learned it now, IE is such a nice browser, without it SO would have a lot less questions :).

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question but I don't know why it works so feel free to answer if you know why this happened. I removed the `height:100%` from the `#navHolder` in the jsfiddle and it works. The behvaiour is still really weird and not something I would expect. Maybe it has something to do with the `z-index` or `position:fixed`?

Fixed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noL14v9w/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your `#navHolder` has `height: 100%` and  `z-index: 99`. In the meantime your `.openStartAuditButton` doesn't have a z-index and position set. This means that it is under your  `#navHolder` which covers the whole window. 
As a solution you could set

```
#navHolder{
   height: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out but the question I have is why it still works if you hover over the text? (In IE10 atleast)